# What are the steps to find a publisher and strike a deal to publish the proceedings of a workshop?

Tags: publishers, workshop, proceedings

I help organize a workshop in a conference on machine learning where the conference doesn't publish proceedings for the workshops: the workshops have to do it themselves if they want to.

What are the steps to find a publisher and strike a deal to publish the proceedings of a workshop? (where to find the list of publisher in a given field, what are the typical contract clauses and negotiation points, etc.)

I know that we can publish it ourselves (since in the end publish = hosting some PDFs online) but I'm curious to know how the old-fashioned publishers work.

If that matters for the answer, all papers are written in English and one requirement is that papers are open access or allowed to be posted on arXiv.

Comment: Consider http://ceur-ws.org/ - OA, DBLP-indexed and easy to get into if certain quality requirements are fulfilled.

Comment: Does the overall conference use a particular publisher?

Comment: IME, personal connections

Comment: @lighthousekeeper thanks, looks great! If anyone else is aware of other such options, very welcome.

Comment: @Buffy The main conference is organized that a society that has their own press (in this case, main conference = [AAAI-21](https://aaai.org/Conferences/AAAI-21) ; society = AAAI ; press = [AAAI Press](https://aaai.org/Press/press.php)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [lighthouse keeper](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/48413/lighthouse-keeper) mentioned in  the [comment section](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/156491/what-are-the-steps-to-find-a-publisher-and-strike-a-deal-to-publish-the-proceedi#comment419227_156491), there is no need to "find a publisher and strike a deal to publish the proceedings of a workshop". Instead, for the sake of making science open access and not wasting research buget paying for open access as authors/editors, you should:

### Use [CEUR Workshop Proceedings (CEUR-WS.org)](http://ceur-ws.org/) (gratis for readers/authors/editors/etc., started in 1995, contains over 2500 workshop proceedings).

Workshop proceedings published on CEUR-WS are indexed by DBLP, Google Scholar, and the process to upload workshop proceedings is quite straightforward. Example of workshop proceedings hosted on CEUR-WS: http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-2831/.

For more details on CEUR-WS, see https://zenodo.org/record/3556678#.YHzKge5KjnJ ([mirror](https://archive.ph/yKcAa)) and http://ceur-ws.org/HOWTOSUBMIT.html#FAQ.

Comment: Sorry for accepting my own answer, typically I don't do it but I want the open access solution to be the most visible since spending research budget on paywalls is a shameful waste of funding.

Answer (score 5):

I went through this a few years ago for a conference for which I was the program chair.

Since you want open access, you'll find that the big commercial publishers will want to charge quite a bit (thousands of dollars per paper) to publish your conference proceedings.  For open access publishing, there are a few reputable publishers and lots of disreputable publishers that you'll want to avoid.

One reputable publisher for topics likes yours is Dagstuhl's LIPICS series.

If the society that sponsors the conference has its own in-house publishing arm then that can be a good choice too.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing special about this - go to the publisher's website, find the "contact us" form, and write to them. They'll tell you what they're looking for. Each new project is a approved on a case-by-case basis.

Typical questions to resolve would be whether there's a bulk purchase (without this, chances are very good that the project will not be profitable) and if so at what price, whether you want the book to be open access and if so how much the [article processing charge (APC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_processing_charge) will be, what format the raw manuscript will be submitted in (can you get all participants to submit camera-ready copies?), and how quickly after the workshop you want the proceedings to be published.